# Magento API Third Party Connection

Tags: php, api, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.5

I'm creating a third party application which uses the Magento API to access a users store which I can do easily for my own using my User and API Key set up in my installation however if I was to do the same for the users of my application how would I give them an API Key and set up a User with a Role without asking them to go to their installation and do it manually? Would I need to extend the core API, can this be done via them installing an extension or is there a simpler solution? Thanks in advance!

Also, am I correct in saying if I want to utilize the Magento API for to access someone else's store for them, they need to create a User with a Role set up and they need their own API Key, as if this is incorrect my question is pretty much pointless.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly your going to have to setup a web service of some kind with some custom code that will populate the `api_user` and/or `api_role` tables. Keep in mind your going to have to provide some kind of credentials to the end user regardless as giving an automated means of creating info to access the (yours or their) API is a big security risk to take.  Be careful what is implemented.

Comment: Hi BOOMER, thanks for your response. Populate the tables where? Inside Magento? Would this be done in an extension they could install? Also why must the end user be told the credentials, to prevent any kind of illegal activity by the application? Or do you mean they must know what we are doing?

Comment: @SamJackson, yes, an extension that could create the api user/role.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which APIs you are using. SOAP,XMLRPC or REST? if you are integrating third party application you can go for SOAP or XMLRPC APIs.

First you need to create credential from system>>web services section of Magento admin panel then you can assign role and permission from system>>permission section. 
After setting up the credential section, you can share these credential with your developer to access APIs. You do not need to extend magento core APIs if you do not required any custom data set or get.

you can have API call reference at 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html